# Core-drawer-panel closed on large screens as well?

Tags: html, polymer, material-design

I'm building my first polymer/material design webapp. In it, I'm using a `core-drawer-panel`. It's normal behaviour is that it is opened on large screens, but I want it to behave the same on large screens as on small screens. Is this possible?

```
<body>

    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" rightDrawer>

        <core-header-panel drawer>

            <core-toolbar id="navheader'">

                <span>Menu</span>

            </core-toolbar>

            <core-menu>

                <core-item label="One"></core-item>
                <core-item label="Two"></core-item>

            </core-menu>

        </core-header-panel>

        <core-header-panel main>

        </core-header-panel>

    <core-drawer-panel>

<body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

In the latest release of the polymer core elements (0.5.0), there's a new attribute you can set to `<core-drawer-panel>`which is `forceNarrow`which forces the panel to always be narrow no matter what width or responsive width it deals with.

If this is what you need, just do this:

```
<core-drawer-panel forceNarrow>...</core-drawer-panel>
```

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You can try changing the `responsiveWidth` attribute to something absurdly large.

The `responsiveWidth` attribute specifies at what width do you want the core-drawer-panel to be opened by default.

Example:

```
<core-drawer-panel responsiveWidth="500px">...</core-drawer-panel>
```

This means that above `500px` the core-drawer-panel will be open and below `500px` the panel will be closed and you'll have to toggle it on and off either by swiping or pressing a menu button you hooked onto it.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered with the newer `forceNarrow` attribute, but I think there is some distinction still that needs to be made with the default behavior.

When using `forceNarrow` on larger screens, you can still toggle the drawer open with the `togglePanel()` method, but this still behaves like it would on smaller screens by creating a drawer overlay.

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawer" forceNarrow="true">
<div drawer></div>
<div main></div>
</core-drawer-panel>

<script>
...
//  This creates drawer overlay on top of and covering the main content
openDrawer: function(){
    this.$.drawer.togglePanel();
}
</script>
```

This overlay is annoying with a large screen, because the overlays are typically used to conserve space on smaller screens, and you may want to see the entire main area when selecting from a drawer.

If you want the main content to resize with the new drawer, try this with polymer:

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawer" forceNarrow="{{drawerNarrow}}">
<div drawer></div>
<div main></div>
</core-drawer-panel>

<script>
...
//  This resizes the main content to accommodate the drawer
drawerNarrow: true,
openDrawer: function(){
    this.drawerNarrow = !this.drawerNarrow
}
</script>
```

This allows you to load the closed drawer on larger screens, and then resizes all of the content on the larger screen when you open it.